How can I select 2 corner edges which make 90 degrees between them on a grid
I would need help with this please.
I want to select the corner edges which make 90 degrees. And then, I already have in the setup the mesh to points on the specific corner edges.
Thank you

With Blender and Geometry Nodes. In my setup I already deleted the inside of the grid and only have the perimeter curve.

2D solution
This solution evaulates at vertex domain:

vertices that have 2 edges (and only 2); and
the angle between the edges is 90

PS: you can remove the "has 2 edges" verification in case you need, but in a grid, all the edges will be selected unless you delete the center

Example:
Source mesh:

Result:

3D solution
This solution evaluates for each "face corner":

Corners whose edges form a 90 degree angle

If the edges fors faces, the faces are preserved, if not, only the edges are selected.

Example:
Source mesh:

Result:

The weird floating edges are within the "tolerance" (epsilon) in the angle comparison. When we deal with float values in computers, we can't use "equal", we always need a tolerance. We can lower it for those edges to disappear, but there is a limit for how much you can lower it without getting unstable results.

"we always need a tolerance" - theoretically there are specific situations when you don't need it, but working with this attitude I managed to provoke some bugs like this one - you'd think the normals of a bounding box would always consist of a single integer component $1$ and two zeroes, and yet not exactly…

As a software developer, hoping to get exact float values is completely out of question.

Oh wow! This is epic! Thank you so much! I have been stuck here, now I can move on.

Great, @GeoNeo, please consider marking it as answered to close the post.

@DanielMöller here's na example where the ε=0 is fine: https://i.imgur.com/lFux8PM.png

@MarkusvonBroady, well... just because you're comparing a number with itself. There is no mathematic operation involved.

@DanielMöller - accepted as answer! Thank you!

@DanielMöller in the case of the normal, there isn't really any maths either: the bounding box should have all top vertices on equal z, the normal should be <0, 0, 1>,the z component should be 1, so it's just number comparing too, but it failed for some reason :

@MarkusvonBroady, well... depending on the Z itself, it might not be a round value (some values that seem roud are impossible in float, they're represented round, but they're not exact), also, the normals might be a "calculation" from vertices instead of a stored value. You start multiplying/dividing things, rounding errors will definitely appear.
